# Django ManyToMany Field Not Accepting Correct Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to make a manytomany field from a model that is not the model that the manytomany field will contain a list of.  e.g.

```
class Following(models.Model):
    following_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    following_user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="following_user")
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="following")
```

This looks all good to me, but when I try to enter the shell and do something like `User.following.add(OtherUser)`, I get an error saying that it was expecting `OtherUser` to be an instance of `Following`.  Why is this?  Did I not specify that the ManyToManyField was storing User instances when I declared the `following` variable?

`models.ManyToManyField(**User**, related_name="following")`

Answer (score 1):

1 - Create a user : `user = User(); user.save()`

2 - Create a following : `following = Following(); following.save()`

3 - Add the user to the following : `following.following.add(user)`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a model with other model only once. But you are using `User model` two times, one with `following_user field` and other with `following field`. Look below your model.

```
class Following(models.Model):
    following_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    following_user = models.ForeignKey(*User*, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="following_user")
    following = models.ManyToManyField(*User*, related_name="following")
```

Comment: I can do this because I added the related_name keyword argument.  That doesn't seem to be the trouble.  I can call on both following_user set and following set with no issues.  The issue is what I described.  Also, I need to use User twice for my program to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.

To work around this problem, every time you save a form using commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data. For example: